# Color buildings in Google Android maps API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm a bit new to Android, so please go easy on me.

I am in the process of building an Android application of my University campus. I am currently using my the Google maps API (V2).

To cut to the chase, I want to color each building on my campus a certain color (some blue, some green etc). However, I can't seem to find a way to do this (except maybe by using a GroundOverlay picture that is the exact size and orientation of the building, but this is extremely tedious).

Does anybody have any better ideas? Am I missing a method that can do this for me easily?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Ground overlays would probably be your best bet in 2D.  I don't think there's any way to color the buildings in 3D.  That might be a good suggestion for Google.